# How to loop and select the appended elements to get .text() and .data() values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have appended a few div's dynamically and stored values using the below code:

```
var $element = $('<div class="draggablebox" />').text(component.children(':selected').text()).css({
  width: wbox.val() * 2,
  height: lbox.val() * 2,
  padding: '0.5em',
  border: '2px solid',
  'user-select': 'none',
  'background-color': 'gray',
  cursor: 'pointer',
  // position: 'absolute',
  // 'font-size': '',
  block: 'inline'
});
$element.attr('id', component.val());
$('#convas').append($element);
```

Then I'm trying to loop through the elements to get `data()` values of each of the elements using the below code. The output I'm getting `text()` of div's together in the same cell.

```
$('#convas').each(function(i, item) {
  var row = '<tbody> <tr>';
  row += '<td>' + $(item).text() + '</td>';
  row += '<td>' + $(item).data('l') * $(item).data('w') + '</td>';
  row += '<td>' + $(item).data('height') + '</td>';
  row += '<td>' + $(item).data('quality') + '</td>';
  row += '<td>' + $(item).data('minrate') + '</td>';
  row += '<td>' + $(item).data('maxrate') + '</td>';
  row += '<td>' + $(item).data('minTotal') + '</td>';
  row += '<td>' + $(item).data('maxTotal') + '</td>';
  row += '</tr> </tbody>';
  console.log($(item).data('l'));
  $('table#report-table').append(row);
});
```

Comment: `#convas` seems to be the parent. I presume you want to loop through the `div` you appended to that, so use `$('#convas .draggablebox').each(...` instead. If that doesn't solve your problem then we need to see a much more complete example of the problem in otder to help you debug it

Comment: I also assume that `data-l` and `data-w` are added to the element later,as they're not in the element you append.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That's clearly the problem, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: you saved lot's of my time man, thank you so much. please post it as answer i really have to give you that green tick!! @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. I added the answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#convas` seems to be the parent. I presume you want to loop through the `div` elements you appended to that, so use this instead:

```
$('#convas .draggablebox').each(function(i, item) {
  // your code here...
});
```